# explode string and set key for array with text that is in front of the delimiter?

Tags: php

Is there a way to take an input like this:

```
|
testing==one two three
|
setting==more testing
|
```

and get something like this

```
array['testing'] = "one two three";
array['setting'] = "more testing"
```

Right now I'm just exploding the string and setting the array with numbered index, but I'd like the user to be able to enter the items in any order and be able to use the array with keys from the first value.

```
function get_desc_second_part(&$value)  {
  list(,$val_b) = explode('==',$value);
  $value = trim($val_b);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? The pipes adds some maybe needless complexity (separator could be new lines):

```
$arr = array();
foreach (explode('|', $str_input) as $line) {
    $l = explode('==', trim($line));
    if (isset($l[1]))
        $arr[$l[0]] = $l[1];
}
print_r($arr);

/*
Array
(
    [testing] => one two three
    [setting] => more testing
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You already do most of the work when you explode on `==`, an array index can be manually set to a string and you already separate out the string.  Just set your array entries manually,

```
$myarray = new array();
$myarray[$your_exploded_1st_part_string_here] = exploded_second_part
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the format of the input to the standard ini format then you could simply call `parse_ini_file`/`parse_ini_string`. Your input would need to look like:

```
testing = one two three
setting = more testing
```

This would also give you comments (start lines with `;`) and sections for free. See http://www.php.net/parse_ini_file