# Converting a string into an array

Tags: php

I have a string - something like

```
$string = 'key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3';
```

How can I get an array from the given string like the following?

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3',
);
```

Comment: Why you are not using google ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100530/explode-string-and-set-key-for-array-with-text-that-is-in-front-of-the-delimiter

Comment: what's the original source of the string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
parse_str(str_replace(", ","&",$string),$array);
```

Answer (score 3):

A naive solution could be :

```
$string = 'key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3';

$array = array();
foreach (explode(', ', $string) as $couple) {
    list ($key, $value) = explode('=', $couple);
    $array[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($array);
```

And you'd get the expected array as a result :

```
array
  'key1' => string 'value1' (length=6)
  'key2' => string 'value2' (length=6)
  'key3' => string 'value3' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [parse_str](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) do. In your case, you need to replace your commas with a `&`:

```
$string = 'key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3';
$array = parse_str(str_replace(', ', '&', $string));

// Yields
array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = explode(', ', $string);
$array = array();
foreach($a as $v){
    $x = explode('=', $v);
    $array[$x[0]] = $x[1];
}
```